# PHP script does not work

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have got a question: I cant figure out why this php script does not work:

```
<?php

 echo "VERSION 1.0";

 ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);


$username ="user";
$password = "pw";
$database = "db";
$mysqldb = "dbName";

echo "INIT OF VARIABLES END";

$conn = mysql_connection("host",$username,$password) or die 
("Failed to connect"); 

echo "CONN FINISCHED";

mysql_select_db("dbSave",$conn);

echo "SELECT DONE";

$login = $_POST["login"];
$pw = $_POST["pw"];

echo "GOT DATA:$login, $pw";

$query = "INSERT INTO dbSave (login, pw) VALUES ("$login","$pw");
mysql_query($query);

echo "EINTRAG GEMACHT";

?>
```

I just get a blank page, not even a error message
(changed the variable names)

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not do code debugging. You need to do your own debugging and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what is is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: Also, stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated and going away eventually. Also also, `mysql_connection()` doesn't exist, it's `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also, `mysql_connection()` should probably be `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: @ceejayoz --> https://gist.github.com/3881905 ^_^

Answer (score 1):

1. **Make sure you have errors turned on**
2. You can see your issue right in the markdown parser:

   ```
   $query = "INSERT INTO dbSave (login, pw) VALUES ("$login","$pw");
   mysql_query($query);

   echo "EINTRAG GEMACHT";
   ```

   You need to escape the double quotes!

   ```
   $query = "INSERT INTO dbSave (login, pw) VALUES (\"$login\",\"$pw\");
   mysql_query($query);

   echo "EINTRAG GEMACHT";
   ```